# reactive data table working with rhandsontable but not with dq_render_handsontable

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

I am trying to build a rhandsontable, but this time using dq_render_handsontable as it gives additional functionality to put nice filters and pagination.
In my app i am filtering the data twice based on picker input, this creating two reactive data frames... filter_tbl_1() after first fitering and filter_tbl_2() after 2nd.

The dq_render_handsontable function works fine with filter_tbl_1() data and provides correct filtering. But with filter_tbl_2(), it throws an error. My guess is that it is not able to recognize the filter_tbl_2(). More than that there is no information shown in Error. Will appreciate if someone can help

The minimum reproducible code:

```
library(dqshiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    column(
        width = 4,
        pickerInput(inputId = "carb_input", 
                    label = "Pick carb",
                    choices = mtcars %>% pull(carb) %>% unique(),
                    selected = mtcars %>% pull(carb) %>% unique(),
                    multiple = TRUE,
                    options = pickerOptions(
                        actionsBox = TRUE,
                        liveSearch = TRUE,
                        size = 10
                    )),
        pickerInput(inputId = "gear_input", 
                    label = "Pick Gear",
                    choices = NULL,
                    multiple = TRUE,
                    options = pickerOptions(
                        actionsBox = TRUE,
                        liveSearch = TRUE,
                        size = 10
                    ))
    ),
    column(
        width = 8,
        dq_handsontable_output("review_table", 8L),
        rHandsontableOutput("test")
    )


)

server <- function(input,output,session){
    filter_tbl_1 <- reactive({
        mtcars %>% rowid_to_column() %>% filter(carb %in% input$carb_input)
    })

    observeEvent(filter_tbl_1(),{
        choices <- filter_tbl_1() %>% pull(gear) %>% unique()
        updatePickerInput(session, "gear_input", choices = choices, selected = choices)
    })

    filter_tbl_2 <- reactive({
        req(input$gear_input)
        filter_tbl_1() %>% filter(gear %in% input$gear_input)
    })



    dq_render_handsontable("review_table",
                           data = reactive(filter_tbl_1()))

    output$test <- renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(filter_tbl_2()))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

In line **dq_render_handsontable("review_table",
                           data = reactive(filter_tbl_1()))**, if you replace **filter_tbl_1()** with **filter_tbl_2()**, you will see the error.